# Is it safe to use function-like macro in C to access a matrix element?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I have a matrix struct defined like this:

```
struct matrix_double_complex
{
    double complex *data;
    int number_of_rows;
    int number_of_columns;
};

typedef struct matrix_double_complex MatrixDoubleComplex;
```

I use 1D dynamical array to store matrix elements, because I want to store them in a single memory block.

The struct is initialized in this function:

```
MatrixDoubleComplex * matrix_double_complex_initialize(int number_of_rows, int number_of_columns)
{
    MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix;

    matrix = (MatrixDoubleComplex *)malloc( sizeof(MatrixDoubleComplex) );

    
    if(matrix == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "matrix_double_complex_initialize: Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    matrix->data = (double complex *)malloc( (number_of_rows)*(number_of_columns)*sizeof(double complex) );

    
    if( (matrix->data) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "matrix_double_complex_initialize: Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    matrix->number_of_rows = number_of_rows;
    matrix->number_of_columns = number_of_columns;

    return matrix;
}
```

But I can't use a convenient syntax like `matrix->data[i][j]` to access matrix element.

I know that I need to calculate index:
`matrix->data[ (i - 1)*(matrix->number_of_columns) + (j - 1) ]` .

But this is ugly syntax.

I have "set" and "get" functions to access matrix element:

```
void matrix_double_complex_set_element(MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix, int i, int j, double complex z)
{
    matrix->data[ (i - 1)*(matrix->number_of_columns) + (j - 1) ] = z;
}

double complex matrix_double_complex_get_element(MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix, int i, int j)
{
    return ( matrix->data[ (i - 1)*(matrix->number_of_columns) + (j - 1) ] );
}
```

But I can't use these functions as a left side. Also I need to use some extra variables and function calls.

```
void matrix_double_complex_add(MatrixDoubleComplex *result, MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix_1, MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix_2)
{
    if( matrices_double_complex_have_the_same_dimension(result, matrix_1) == false )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "matrix_double_complex_add: Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( matrices_double_complex_have_the_same_dimension(matrix_1, matrix_2) == false )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "matrix_double_complex_add: Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    double complex result_ij;
    double complex matrix_1_ij;
    double complex matrix_2_ij;
        
    for(int i = 1; i <= (result->number_of_rows); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= (result->number_of_columns); j++)
        {
            matrix_1_ij = matrix_double_complex_get_element(matrix_1, i, j);
            matrix_2_ij = matrix_double_complex_get_element(matrix_2, i, j);

            result_ij = matrix_1_ij + matrix_2_ij;

            matrix_double_complex_set_element(result, i, j, result_ij);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that function-like macros can be used:

```
#define MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(matrix,i,j) ( \
  (matrix)->data[ ((i) - 1)*((matrix)->number_of_columns) + ((j) - 1) ] \
)
```

With this macro I can conviniently write something like this:

```
MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(result,i,j) = MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(matrix_1,i,j) + MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(matrix_2,i,j);

MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(result,i,j) = conj( MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(matrix,j,i) );
```

So, my question: Is it safe to use this macro? Can it lead to undefined behavior under some circumstances?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the macro. There are not many things that can lead to UB in the preprocessor context, and none of these is present here. Sure it can lead to UB if `matrix` is `NULL` for example, but it is really not related to the fact it is a macro.

Comment: It is safe just put alot of ()

Comment: Do you want to use index `1 .. number_of_rows` instead of the usual `0 .. (number_of_rows -1)`? This could be confusing for C programmers.

Comment: Bodo, I'm not sure about it. But mathematicians usually write matrix elements as a_{11}, a_{12},...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you properly parenthesize `i` and `j`, and only use them once, this is safe for those arguments. It's theoretically unsafe for the `matrix` argument if used in complex ways, e.g. using pointer arithmetic with `++`/`--` on a pointer into an array of matrices. In that case, the side-effect of evaluating `matrix` would occur twice, producing undefined behavior when something like:

```
 MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(*matrixptr++, 0, 1)
```

is evaluated (as `matrixptr++` occurs twice in the expanded expression). Similar issues are possible if you're calling a non-idempotent function, or function with side-effects, that produces the `matrix` argument. As long as you stick to simple usage (the `matrix` argument is always a simple variable name), this will work though.

If you want to remove the risk of that sort of misuse, you could use a function that retrieves a *pointer* to the matrix element; dereference the result and it can be used both to read and write that element. A macro could wrap that function if needed, where the macro performs the dereferencing for you, while maintaining the single evaluation behavior the function provides:

```
double complex* matrix_double_complex_get_element_ptr(MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix, int i, int j)
{
    // Returns address of element, not element value
    return &matrix->data[ (i - 1)*(matrix->number_of_columns) + (j - 1) ];
}

#define MATRIX_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_ELEMENT(matrix,i,j) \
  (*matrix_double_complex_get_element_ptr((matrix), (i), (j)))
```

You can use it just like your original, potentially unsafe macro, without the risk of double-evaluating a complex (as in adjective, not data type) `matrix` argument. You can declare the function itself as an explicitly `inline` function to keep the overhead down; the compiler should be able to avoid the take-address-of/dereference two step, leaving the code with performance equivalent to hand-writing the more complex expression.

Answer (score 0):

IMO macros should be avoided and sued only when absolutely necessary.
Macros are extremely error-prone, especially if:

1. You do not use parenthesises
2. You use more than once particular parameter (`#define SQR(x) (x) * (x)`  `y = SQR(x++);`)
3. Function calls inside macros have side effects.

If you are worried about function call overhead - it is very likely that the compiler will inline them automatically. If you know the compiler you can also force inlining.

`gcc` example:

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) double complex* matrix_double_complex_get_element_ptr(MatrixDoubleComplex *matrix, int i, int j)
{
    // Returns address of element, not element value
    return &matrix->data[ (i - 1)*(matrix->number_of_columns) + (j - 1) ];
}
```